# Byte hexadecimal object converting to string

Tags: python-3.x, hex

I am migrating a python 2 code to python 3, then I am having problems with encode/decode. First I have multiples sentence that I should convert in the following way:

string-->string in hexadecimal

Before, in python 2 I was using a code like that `hex_message = message.encode("hex")`, then before to migrate was working perfectly. As an example, `input->"Hello world", output ->"48656c6c6f20776f726c64"`. Then I have this problem `LookupError: 'hex' is not a text encoding; use codecs.encode() to handle arbitrary codecs`. I changed the expression to this `hex_message = codecs.encode(message, 'hex')` and I am getting this output `b"48656c6c6f20776f726c64"`. So, not so many changes, the problem is that I have a multiples strings that they are not byte objects and I have to join them so I would like to encode but not as a byte object only as string. I would like to get them as before with an another function or with an additional function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a solution:

`message = "Hello world".encode('utf-8')` then
`hex_message = message.hex()`. It is working in python3.